# Heights of two points on a circle

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a circle of arbitrary radius centred on C, let each point on the circle have an associated height which varies continuously and smoothly as you go around the circle.

How can I prove or disprove that there will always be at least one pair of diametrically opposite points (i.e. there is a straight line which joins them going through C) which are at the same height? And if true, is there anything special about that height?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), in particular, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem#1-dimensional_case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the height of each point on $C$ is $f(\theta)$ where $\theta$ runs from 0 to $2\pi$. Consider any two diametrically opposite points on $C$, $x$ and $x+\pi$, and their associated heights $f(x)$ and $f(x+\pi)$. Let $h(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x)$ and vary $x$ from 0 to $\pi$; during this movement $h(x)$ will start out at one value and end at its negative. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $h(x)$; since $h(0)=-h(\pi)$, by the intermediate value theorem there is some $0\le x<\pi$ where $h(x)=0$, i.e. the two diametrically opposite points have the same height.

However, there is nothing special about this height other than the antipodal property.

Comment: Would the height in question (H) not be the average of all the heights? In other words, shouldn't there be as many points below H as there are above H? Or is this wrong?

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips The plane corresponding to the mean of the points will intersect the curve in at least two points, yes, but those two points need not be antipodal.

Comment: Accepted. Since h(x) must go positive to negative, continuing round, it must go positive again. So actually, there must be two sets of points at the same height. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips Or rather, at least one pair of points. $\theta=x$ and $\theta=x+\pi$ will yield the same pair.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Borsuk Ulam theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) in the case n=1 and height is a function associating at each x its height, so it is a function from $S^1$ and so the conclusion follows by the theorem.